# What is it called when you change a well known quote to suit your subject?

Tags: quotes, quotations

For example, for the original quote we shall use, "One swallow does not a summer make". If someone were to say "One good quote does not a philosopher make" (No dig at Aristotle intended...), or "A fancy suit does not a businessman make".

Essentially, a clear allusion to a quote, but not the quote itself.

Comment: You mean other than ***"plagiarism"***? ;)

Comment: Thanks all. I was thinking "paraphrasing", but I felt like paraphrasing was essentially shortening a quote to get the original point across in less/simpler words, while keeping the meaning and context the same. Thank you for the definitions to clarify my understanding.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The word I've heard used for this on the linguistics blog *Language Log* is **snowclone** (it's derived from phrases of the format "If Eskimos have N words for snow, X surely have Y words for Z.")

Here's a *Language Log* post that describes the moment the word was coined and that links to some examples: [Snowclones: Lexicographical Dating to the Second](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/000350.html)

And here's how it's defined by [Collins Dictionaries online](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/snowclone):

> a verbal formula that is adapted for reuse by changing only a few
>   words so that the allusion to the original phrase remains clear

You might also be interested in looking at the answers to the following questions:

- [This book will change your wife – trope?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80350/this-book-will-change-your-wife-trope)
- [Is there a general name for this: “The more you X the more you'll Y”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212023/is-there-a-general-name-for-this-the-more-you-x-the-more-youll-y)
- [A term describing the replacement of a specific word in a saying with one that ryhmes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218639/a-term-describing-the-replacement-of-a-specific-word-in-a-saying-with-one-that-r)

Comment: Interesting, is it  just a noun or also a verb?

Comment: The mother of all neologisms. The new crash blossom.

Comment: Thanks for this. Some fascinating reading here and I'll definitely be using the word "snowclone" in general conversation.

Comment: @Josh61: I've only seen it used as a noun.

Comment: @sumelic All nouns can be verbed. :)

Answer (score 11):

I think you are looking for 'to ***[paraphrase](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paraphrase)':***

> - The adaptation or alteration of a text or quotation to serve a different purpose from that of the original.

(AHD)

Answer (score 1):

"Paraphrasing" was already offered, so I'll suggest something more colorful like "hijacking" or "co-opting".

Comment: To "reword" or to "bastardise" are also available.